# Laravel: Loading nested relationship only for related model

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to implement a feature and I don't think it's available by relationships.

A User may have many Companies and Company may have many Users. They are connected via company_employees pivot table.

pivot table looks like this:

```
company_id, user_id, position_id
```

I want to have an option to fetch company employees with their assosiated position.

Let's say there are companies:

1. "Foo Company"
2. "Bar Company"

and user

1. "John Doe"

There are also 2 positions:

1. "Frontend Developer"
2. "Backend Developer"

John Doe is an employee in both of these companies with different position.

```
company_id | user_id | position_id
1            1         1
2            1         2
```

How can i make something like

```
$company = Company::first();
$company->employees()->with('position')->get();
```

return only **position associated with first user** that belongs to first company as HasOne relationship?

Comment: Exactly which model you want to return? I don't really get what do you want to return

Comment: why are employees linked by user ids, and not employee_ids for example?

Comment: @CodeBoyCode There is not such thing as Employee model per se. Employee is simply User associated with Company.

Comment: @CloudSohJunFu I want to return all users that belongs to the company (that works already through many-to-many) and ONLY the POSITION associated with that specific company.

Comment: Make a relations to user and position in pivot_table model and one relation to pivot_table from `Company` model and then try `Company::with(['pivot_table.user','pivot_table.position'])->first();`

Answer (score 1):

```
 Company.php     
    public function user() {
         return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'company_employees ', 'company_id', 
                    'user_id');
    }

    User.php
      public function position() {
            return $this->hasMany('App\Position');
        }


    $company = Company::with('user.position')->get();
```

Comment: This doesn't solve a problem since user may have many positions. Although he can only have one position connected with a company.

Comment: Then it will return all user positions and not only those regarding company.

$company->with('user.positions')->get() based on data from my question will resolve in
company {
User {
position: {
position at first company,
position at second company
}
}
}

Answer (score 0):

I think you can only achieve it by using a custom `with` function.

Untested code:

```
$company = Company::first();
$company->employees()->with([
  'position' => function ($query) use ($company) {
    $query->where('company_id', $company->id);
  }
])->get();
```

Check out the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading).